# I cannot make regexp and preg_replace work

Tags: php

Any ideas why this wouldn't output anything?

I just want to remove /page/* part of the url.

My aim is to get always http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/car-photography/ even if string contains longer url.

I tried:

```
<?php

$url1 = "http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/car-photography/page/1/";
$url2 = "http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/car-photography/page/2/";
$url3 = "http://www.sandrophoto.com/category/car-photography/";

$cleaned1 = preg_replace('/page/*', '', $url1);
$cleaned2 = preg_replace('/page/*', '', $url2);
$cleaned3 = preg_replace('/page/*', '', $url3);

echo "$cleaned1 <br>";
echo "$cleaned2 <br>";
echo "$cleaned3 <br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions require a delimiter, and you are not using one. Additionally, the forward slash followed by an asterisk means "Zero or more forward slashes", when it would seem you want "Forward slash followed by Zero or more non-newline characters", which would be `/.*` instead.

```
preg_replace('/page/*', '', $url1);
```

should be

```
preg_replace('#/page/.*#', '', $url1);
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: ah! how come they say nothing about ## in php help pages!

Comment: 1 more question, is there any performance issue associated with using preg_replace?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze ~If you look at the reference I cited they talk about them~ =) preg functions are significantly more expensive than comparable str functions. If you can think of a way to use str_replace instead of preg_replace that would be better. In this case I cannot see any way to do so.